# How to add and remove from array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of images and I want to insert their `src values` and then add some `div elements` too associated with it into the `array` into the array on a click on the image and remove them if we click again.

Trying the following but I got the logic wrong as it is not removing the already `el`:

**HTML**

```
<div class="card">
  <img src="test_2.jpg">
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="test_2.jpg">
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="test_3.jpg">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('body').on('click', '.card img', function () {
      var urls = [];
      if($(this).hasClass("checked")) {
        $(this).removeClass("checked");
        var urlInArray = $(this).attr('src');
        urls.splice($.inArray(urlInArray, urls), 1);
        console.log(urls);
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("checked");
        var checkedItems = $('.checked'); // get the checked items
        checkedItems.each(function () {
          urls.push($(this).attr('src'));
        });
        var str = '';
        urls.forEach(function (url) {
          str += '<div class="card"><img class="img-fluid" onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" src="' + url + '"></div>';
        });
        console.log(urls);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `splice()` to remove url from array and `indexOf()` to get index of that url.

```js
var urls = [];

$(".card img").click(function() {
  var src = $(this).attr('src')
  $(this).hasClass('checked') ? urls.splice(urls.indexOf(src), 1) : urls.push(src);
  $(this).toggleClass('checked')

  console.log(urls)
})
```

```css
.checked {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <img src="test_1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="test_2.jpg">
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="test_3.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: we're never adding the class checked, if I look in console, it is never added

Answer (score 0):

That's an overkill of bytes. Use simple `indexOf` to check if image is already in `urls`. I don't see how `checked` on `img` tag is semantic, perhaps switch to `data-checked`?

```js
var urls = [];
$('body').on('click', '.card img', function () {
    // src; unique
    var src = $(this).attr('src'),
    // index of src key
        index = urls.indexOf(src);
    // if element exists;
    if(index >= 0){
    // remove
        urls.splice(index, 1);
        
    } else {
    // add to urls
        urls.push(src);
    }

    console.log(urls);
  
});
```

```css
div {
   display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/uK9QFr3fFk0/100x100">
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/pHANr-CpbYM/100x100">
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/39-0VXkvcbw/100x100">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be very simple. [check this](https://jsfiddle.net/76bq2sLL/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var status = {};
    $('body').on('click', '.card img', function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        if (typeof status[src] == 'undefined' || status[src] == false) {
            status[src] = true;
            $(this).next().html('added');
        } else {
            status[src] = false;
            $(this).next().html('removed');
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="card">
  <img src="france_fan.jpg" alt='image_1'>
  <span>removed</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
   <img src="italy-s.gif" alt='image2'>
   <span>removed</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  <img src="bangladesh-s.gif" alt='image3'>
 <span>removed</span>
  </div>
```